# Run AngularJS directive after TypeKit loads font

Tags: angularjs, typekit

I wrote a directive that gives me the position of a piece of text, but the position is incorrect since the directive fires before TypeKit has applied the font.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

            var active = elem.children('li.active');
            console.log( active[0].offsetLeft ); // <-- This is wrong

            elem.bind('click', function(){
                var active = elem.children('li.active');
                console.log( active[0].offsetLeft ); // <-- This is correct
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Any ideas on how to get my directive to fire after the font has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm a bonehead - looks like this only fails when working locally. Once I push to the server the issue is resolved.